# performSelector being called but not performSelector:afterDelay

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code works, and postSpamListUpdatedNotification is called

```
- (void) postSpamListUpdatedNotification
{
    [NIDPrivateUtils postNotification:kNIDSpamListsUpdated andError:nil];
}

[self performSelector:@selector(postSpamListUpdatedNotification) withObject:nil];
```

But if I change it to this, then postSpamListUpdateNotification is never called. Why?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(postSpamListUpdatedNotification) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't have a runloop on this thread. `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` requires a runloop, but `performSelector:` doesn't.